# Yii2 - default value only if the record is new

Tags: forms, yii2, default-value

I want to add a default value (current date) only when the record is new. When I edit the record, the date should not be overwritten.

Comment: please add some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the value of date using model if its new record provide current date and if existing pass the exists date.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it:

```
    <?php
    if ($model->isNewRecord) {
        $form->field($model, 'erstellt_am')->widget(DatePicker::classname(),[
        'options' => [  'value' =>  date('Y-m-d')],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'autoclose' => true,
                            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
                            'todayHighlight' => true,
                            'todayBtn' => true,
                            'timeZone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
                        ]
                    ])
    }
?>
```

Thanks